# Nab transact Omnipay silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe, omnipay, silvershop

could some one please assist with setting up NABTransact payment gateway in omnipay for silverstripe.

I used https://packagist.org/packages/sudiptpa/omnipay-nabtransact, and I'm currently getting this error "[User Error] Uncaught Omnipay\Common\Exception\RuntimeException: Class '\Omnipay\NABTransact\Gateway' not found"

Comment: Please show us your code, and exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: @Rey Did you install it using composer? Is that class in that package? Might be a dependency problem, could be a but... hard to tell without code. BTW: There is a gitter silverstripe-omnipy channel for instant help: https://gitter.im/silverstripe/silverstripe-omnipay

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I have installed it via composer. There is no instructions for the NABTransact package.  The only code I have is my payment.yml

Comment: "Name: payment
Payment:
  file_logging: 1
  allowed_gateways:
    - 'Dummy'
    - 'Manual'
    - 'NABTransact Direct Post'
The Dummjy and manual payment gateway seems to work myabe its the class name I'm using for NABTransact in my payment.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow [gateway naming conventions](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-omnipay#gateway-naming-conventions) when defining your gateway parameters and `allowed_gateways`.

So your config should read:

```
Payment:
  allowed_gateways:
    - NABTransact_DirectPost
```